# How to find unqiue file extensions in python pandas dataframe, series?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a csv file that contains hundreds of images path and text file path with different extensions. Now i want to find the unique extension of these images and text files. How do i do that?
eg of data contained in csv file:

images_path:

```
https://img.sportstars.id/2021/07/h4bc44/master_B7Nrz3845M_1077.JPG               
https://img.sportstars.id/2021/04/M17c3d/master_04fdj7Zi27_1560.jpg               
https://img.sportstars.id/2021/07/j6KY90/master_9uYf5T2Y97_1940.jpg
```

text_path:

```
xNeW1g.txt
YnENun.txt
tstaxy.txt
```

Note: both text and image path are contained in same csv as column names. Please any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: In addition to @Tranbi solution, you can do: `df['images_extensions'] = df.images_path.apply(lambda x: os.path.splitext(x)[-1])` and then to get all the unique extensions: `df.images_extensions.unique()`

Comment: Finally, found the solution. Thanks to both of you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [@tzinie's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69881327/how-to-find-unqiue-file-extensions-in-python-pandas-dataframe-series#comment123527660_69881327):

```py
df['images_extensions'] = df['images_path'].apply(lambda x: os.path.splitext(x)[-1])
```